# Input seems to be putting out correct string, but isn't accepted

Tags: c++, string, char

So I'm trying to make a dumb little console response thing because I'm bored, but for some reason it doesn't accept it as a correct answer whenever you try to delete something. The string looks fine, but when I try to check it with `if(a==b)` or the like it won't have any of it. Here's the code:

```
string entry(){
    string input = "";
    char ch = getch();
    while (ch != '\r'){
        if (ch != '.'){
            ch = tolower(ch);
            input += ch;
            cout<<ch;
            ch = getch();
        }
        else if (ch == '.'){
            cout<<ch;
            ch=getch();
        }
        else if (ch == '\b'){
            cout<<'\b';
            input.resize((input.length()-1));
        }
    }
    cout << "\n"+input;
    return input;
}
```

This would be used by something like `a=entry();`, but, as I've already stated, it doesn't work for any `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 conditions that cover the whole spectrum and then another condition - which would never be taken:

```
if (ch != '.') {
   // something
else if (ch == '.') {
   // something else
}
```

If `ch` isn't `.` or is a `.` covers all options. It is equivalent to

```
if (ch != '.') {
   // something
else {
   // something else
}
```

You need to exclude the `\b` char from the 1st if.

Answer (score 0):

The `ch == '\b'` can never be reached as the first if (`ch != '.'`) also matches that case. Maybe revert the order:

```
    if (ch == '.'){
        cout<<ch;
        ch=getch();
    }
    else if (ch == '\b'){
        cout<<'\b';
        input.resize((input.length()-1));
    }
    else{
        ch = tolower(ch);
        input += ch;
        cout<<ch;
        ch = getch();
    }
```

Comment: That broke when I pressed backspace.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the input.resize((input.length()-1)); bit.

Comment: @Xarathorn You probably need to check if `input` is empty first.